# "Fatal Error" in My Code. Not sure what it could be

Tags: android

This is my code so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/jeans"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i try to run it on my emulator it just kills itself. I have another code which is almost identical and it works fine, so I have no idea what is wrong with this.

EDIT: this is my java code

```
package com.example.seconlisttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: which error you have.can you show your logcat here.and also the activity where you use this layout.

Comment: your xml code works fine, could you provide stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the actual Java code for your app that uses this XML?

Comment: you could have placed this as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: My apologies. I think I meant to place it as a comment. I was pretty tired last night.